# Filter a value of nested key of json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account_details
(
    account_id integer,
    condition json
)
```

And the data's present inside this table are

| account_id | condition |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[35,20,5,6]}}}] |
| 2 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[1,4,2,3]}}}] |
| 3 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[5]}}}] |
| 4 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[1,2,3,5]}}}] |
| 5 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[3,4]}}}] |
| 6 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[4]}}}] |
| 7 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[3]}}}] |

I need to fetch part of values present inside **rootcompanyid**

Please guide me how to filter nested JSON data

**Expected Output**

**Case: 1**

Whenever I pass input rootcompanyid = 5 to the below query, it should filter out account_id 1,3 and 4 details

```
SELECT *
  FROM account_details
 WHERE ((condition->0->>'conditions')::json->>'rootcompanyid')::json->>'$in' = 5;
```

| account_id | condition |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[35,20,**5**,6]}}}] |
| 3 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[**5**]}}}] |
| 4 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[1,2,3,**5**]}}}] |

**Case: 2**

Whenever I pass input rootcompanyid = 3,4 to the below query, it should filter out account_id 2,4,5,6 and 7 details

```
SELECT *
  FROM account_details
 WHERE ((condition->0->>'conditions')::json->>'rootcompanyid')::json->>'$in' = 3,4;
```

| account_id | condition |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[1,**4**,2,**3**]}}}] |
| 4 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[1,2,**3**,5]}}}] |
| 5 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[**3**,**4**]}}}] |
| 6 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[**4**]}}}] |
| 7 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[**3**]}}}] |

Comment: Does a list always have only one element?

Comment: Yes @DanilaGanchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the element in the nested `json`. [Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r3Bd1T8Hr84wuQJg7um1d7/0) is an example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM account_details
 WHERE ((condition->0->>'conditions')::json->>'rootcompanyid')::json->>'$in' = '[35,20,5,6]';
```

`condition->0` - first element of array

`->>'conditions')::json` - extract `conditions` from first element of array

`->>'rootcompanyid')::json` - extract `rootcompanyid` from `conditions`

`::json->>'$in'` - extract `$in` from `rootcompanyid` (id's of `rootcompanyid`)

Search by action:

```
SELECT *
  FROM account_details
 WHERE condition->0->>'action' = 'read';
```

**Updated**

To search specific `id` in `json array` you can use `@>` operator:

```
SELECT *
  FROM account_details
 WHERE ((((condition->0->>'conditions')::json->>'rootcompanyid')::json->>'$in')::jsonb) @> '[3,1]'::jsonb
```

Or `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM account_details
 WHERE ((condition->0->>'conditions')::json->>'rootcompanyid')::json->>'$in' LIKE '%5%';
```

**Updated v2**

You can use `json_array_elements_text` + `exists`:

```
WITH parsed_conditions AS (
    SELECT account_id,
           json_array_elements_text(
               (((condition -> 0 ->> 'conditions')::json ->> 'rootcompanyid')::json ->>'$in')::json
           ) AS json_id
      FROM account_details
)

SELECT *
  FROM account_details AS a
 WHERE exists(
    SELECT DISTINCT account_id
      FROM parsed_conditions
     WHERE json_id IN ('3', '1')
       AND parsed_condidtions.account_id = a.account_id
);
```

Comment: Sometimes we have [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[35,20,5,6]}}}]. And I need to fetch part of value present inside the condition too. Please give a solution how to fetch lists having single and multiple part of rootcompanyid's are present inside the condition

Comment: @Subramanya show a few records and expected output please

Comment: I have edited my expected output for processing these JSON conditions. Please give me the solution as I'm new to PostgreSQL and JSON

Comment: updated query was helpful in other scenarios but the query -----> WHERE ((((condition->0->>'conditions')::json->>'rootcompanyid')::json->>'$in')::jsonb) @> '[3,1]'::jsonb ----> As per your query and from expected output, last row i.e account_id = 7 has not displayed. Output is giving 2 rows instead of 3. Please give me the solution for this scenario

Comment: The query -----> WHERE ((((condition->0->>'conditions')::json->>'rootcompanyid')::json->>'$in')::jsonb) @> '[3,1]'::jsonb ------> is checking combination of {3 and 1} root company id's are present in each and every row but it is not checking either 3 or 1 alone in each and every rows. This query  excluded output for account_id's 5 and 7